# Binding single json result on xaml view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, viewmodel

I have trouble in binding a single json result to view. There is no problem in binding to List View on Xaml. Can anyone help me binding individual values of Json result to xaml.

My Json Result

```
{
    "id": "37",
    "full_name": "Priyanka",
    "celeb_id": "37",
    "profile_pic_1": "http://192.168.1.6/yoyo/uploads/form_celebrity_assets/20190316182711-2019-03-16form_celebrity_assets182607.jpg",
    "profile_pic_2": "20190316182711-2019-03-16form_celebrity_assets182616.jpg",
    "profile_pic_3": "20190316182711-2019-03-16form_celebrity_assets182624.jpg"
}
```

Here is my Model

```
public partial class CelebrityList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_1 { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_2 { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_3 { get; set; }
    public string Likes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Services for API call

```
public async Task<List<CelebrityList>> GetAllLiveNowAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        accessToken = CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue("AccessToken");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", "659D35BF572E789B3A0400F8C6F76D86");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Token", accessToken);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(Constants.BaseApiAddress + "celebrity_merge_user_with_assets/all");
        Debug.Write(json);
        var livenow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CelebrityList>>(json);
        Debug.Write(livenow);
        return livenow;
    }
```

My view Model

```
private async Task GetList()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;

        var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
        Livenow = await _apiServices.GetAllLiveNowAsync(accessToken);

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
```

I just need to bind the result on xaml on different elements, say image binded to ffimageloading resource, name to label and so on.

I have no trouble in loading all them as list.

Comment: You can use index in binding. As per your question, if you set datacontext to some parent element, it ll be automatically bound to first element of list.
In case if you have fixed number of elements but not in list control, use index. like image1 binds to Livenow[0].profile_pic_1  and so on

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the XAML file? My guess is: you are trying to bind to `Livenow`. I assume it is either a List or IList. Change it to `ObservableCollection` like this

```
var listOfcelebritiesList = await _apiServices.GetAllLiveNowAsync(accessToken);
if(celebrityList!=null)
{
    Livenow = new ObservableCollection(listOfcelebritiesList);
}
```

Make sure that the *celebrityList* is not null or empty. If it is filled and you binded ListView source to Livenow & cells inside to CelebrityList then I think this should do.

Comment: BTW. Your naming is not that good. GetAllLiveNowAsync doesn't tell what output you can expect. Secondly, I don't quite understand why CelebrityList is not a List (based on name it should be list) & why is it marked as partial class. What's more, I believe that `Livenow` is also not that good as it does not say anything